# SQL Query for a running aggregate of date value - 365 days with SUM and GROUP BY clauses involved

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, aggregate-functions

Setup: SQL Server 2012 with data being used in a line graph in SSRS using Report Builder 3.0

I have a table with sales data with the first transaction being on 10/10/2012. This table gets written to regularly updating the sales information and will continue to be written to into the future (current date being 11/26/13, which is why the sample table stops there).

Here's a sample of the original data I'm starting with:

```
StartDate          Product         PaidQty          UnPaidQty
-------------------------------------------------------------
2012-10-10         Product A       100              150
2012-10-10         Product B       110              50
2012-10-10         Product C       10               100
2012-10-11         Product A       120              200
2012-10-11         Product D       140              230
2012-10-11         Product E       180              20
...
2013-05-01         Product H       120              60
2013-05-01         Product J       90               90
2013-05-01         Product K       120              160
...
2013-11-25         Product B       90               80
2013-11-25         Product F       190              180
2013-11-25         Product G       120              60
```

NOTE: There may not be values for every date. For instance there isn't a row for 12/25/12.

What I want to end with should look like this:

```
StartDate          DailyTotal      AnnualTotal
--------------------------------------------
2012-10-10         520             520       <-- The Sum of 10/10/12 through 10/10/12
2012-10-11         890             1410      <-- The Sum of 10/10/12 through 10/11/12
...
2013-05-01         640             278,000   <-- The Sum of 10/10/12 through 05/01/13
...
2013-11-25         720             450,500   <-- The Sum of 11/26/12 through 11/25/13
```

Getting the daily total column, combining PaidQty and UnPaidQty is simple enough:

```
SELECT StartDate, SUM(PaidQty) + SUM(UnPaidQty) AS Total
FROM Table
GROUP BY StartDate
ORDER BY StartDate
```

But, I need to end up with data that provides me a daily total (Paid + UnPaid) as well as a running total of the previous 365 days. So because no data exists prior to 10/10/2012, the running total will sum the totals from 10/10/2012 until 10/11/2013 at which point it will sum the totals of the `StartDate` value - 365 days. There is a large list of products, any of which can be sold on any day, but for my end result, I don't care about the products. This information comes into play with the use of the `GROUP BY` clause in order to return a single row for each date.

I'm just not grasping what I would need to do in order to add an additional column for a running annual total. I've tried using an `OVER()` clause, such as:

```
SELECT StartDate, SUM(PaidQty) + SUM(UnPaidQty) AS Total, SUM(PaidQty) + SUM(UnPaidQty) OVER (ORDER BY StartDate) AS AnnualTotal
FROM Table
GROUP BY StartDate
ORDER BY StartDate
```

But this errors out with the message that PaidQty and UnPaidQty need to be in an aggregate function or `GROUP BY` clause. If I add the those to the `GROUP BY` clause, then I end up with multiple rows for each date again and the running value isn't correct.

EDIT: As suggested by Aaron's answer below, I've ended up with the following query:

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#x') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #x 
CREATE TABLE #x
(
    StartDate   DATETIME,
    PaidQty     INT,
    UnPaidQty   INT
)
INSERT INTO #x
SELECT StartDate, SUM(PaidQty), SUM(UnPaidQty)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY StartDate

SELECT Date, PaidQty+UnPaidQty AS DailyTotal, 
            SUM(PaidQty+UnPaidQty) OVER (Order By Date ROWS 364 PRECEDING) AS AnnualTotal
FROM CalendarDates
LEFT JOIN #x ON Date = StartDate
WHERE Date BETWEEN '2012-10-10' AND GetDate()
ORDER BY Date
```

I created a table in my database called CalendarDates that simply contains a list of all dates from 1/1/2010 through 12/31/2100. This is used to fill in NULL for any dates that no sales were completed.

Comment: So you care about per-day totals and not per-product totals?

Comment: Correct. I just want to know the total number of products by day. I don't want to break it down by product.

Comment: So you want to include data from before the begin date? So what is the point of the begin date then?

Comment: The use of parameters, including the begin date, was a way of simplifying the query that you provided. I acknowledge that data prior to `@Begin` would be excluded, which isn't what I want. "...the initial date defined by `@Begin` doesn't really need to come into play. I can use SSRS to filter the results to a more defined date range"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @x TABLE(StartDate DATE, Product VARCHAR(30), PaidQty INT, UnPaidQty INT);

INSERT @x VALUES
('2012-10-10','Product A',100,150),
('2012-10-10','Product B',110,50 ),
('2012-10-10','Product C',10 ,100),
('2012-10-11','Product A',120,200),
('2012-10-11','Product D',140,230),
('2012-10-11','Product E',180,20 ),
('2012-10-12','Product B',90 ,80 ),
('2012-10-12','Product F',190,180),
('2012-10-12','Product G',120,60 );

;WITH x AS
(
  SELECT StartDate, pq = SUM(PaidQty), uq = SUM(UnPaidQty)
  FROM @x GROUP BY StartDate
)
SELECT StartDate, pq, uq,
  SUM(pq+uq) OVER (ORDER BY StartDate ROWS 365 PRECEDING)
FROM x;
```

Now, this assumes that you will have a row for every date. If not, you may want to generate a set of dates and use that as an anchor in a left join. Otherwise the previous 365 rows will represent more than 365 days. To do this:

```
DECLARE @minDate DATE, @maxDate DATE, @delta INT;

SELECT @maxDate = MAX(StartDate), @minDate = MIN(StartDate) FROM @x;

SET @delta = DATEDIFF(DAY, @minDate, @maxDate);

IF @delta > 364
  SELECT @minDate = DATEADD(DAY, -364, @maxDate), @delta = 364;

;WITH n(n) AS
(
  SELECT TOP (@delta+1) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])
  FROM sys.all_columns
),
d(d) AS (SELECT DATEADD(DAY, n-1, @minDate) FROM n),
x AS 
(
  SELECT StartDate = d.d, pq = SUM(PaidQty), uq = SUM(UnPaidQty)
    FROM d LEFT OUTER JOIN @x AS x 
    ON d.d = x.StartDate GROUP BY d.d
)
SELECT StartDate, pq, uq,
  SUM(pq+uq) OVER (ORDER BY StartDate ROWS 365 PRECEDING)
FROM x
ORDER BY StartDate;
```

Comment: This works well except for the assumption that there's a row for every date. There will be a few dates a year without any data, and I won't necessarily be able to go in and keep adding dates every time there's a day without a sale. I'm also modifying your final `SELECT` statement a bit as I need the total, not paid total vs unpaid total. So I used this instead `SUM(pq+uq) OVER (ORDER BY StartDate ROWS 365 PRECEDING)`. Minor detail but I wanted to be clear as to what I needed to accomplish.

Comment: @BobbyScon I mentioned the missing date as part of my answer - I don't think it's my fault for making such an assumption; if there are missing days then that should be part of the problem statement.

Comment: No attitude/offense intended. I even up voted your answer because it's correct, but I didn't accept it as the final answer because it's not quite what I need. My original question is looking for the previous 365 days, not previous 365 values. I'm sorry I wasn't clearer with that.

Comment: @BobbyScon yes, if you have missing dates, you should make that clear. Your sample data could have left a date out, for example. If you provide contiguous sample data, the logical assumption is that all of your data is contiguous.

Comment: My original question, and sample data, was provided under the premise that the answer would contain some form of `OVER()` statement that contained a constraint based on calendar date, rather than counting rows. I like your approach, and by no means discredit your point, but until I saw what you did to approach the problem, I didn't consider that missing dates would come into play. Your proposed solution is far more complex than I originally anticipated the answer being, so I'm grateful for the full response you've provided.

Comment: Hey Aaron, if you could, please take a look at my edit to the original question regarding the dates returned by your query. Thanks for your help so far, I appreciate the patience.

Comment: @BobbyScon You're going to have to provide better sample data, period. I can't troubleshoot why the query somehow starts at 11/26/2012 when the only mention of that data point is in the word problem.

Comment: OK, I've reworded the original question and elaborated on the initial sample data along with providing some example tables of what I'm trying to see when I get the right query in place. Let me know what else I can clarify on.